# What is wrong with this Smarty php templating code?

Tags: php, smarty

What is wrong with this Smarty php templating code? If I include either of these two loops individually in the file, they work. But if I have them both in the file like below only the first loop gets completed.

```
  {include file="vote_js.tpl"}
    {section name=i loop=$posts}
    {include file="posts_bitother.tpl"}
    {/section}



    {section name=j loop=$posts2}
    {include file="posts_bitposts.tpl"}
    {/section}
```

So for example

```
   {section name=j loop=$posts2}
    {include file="posts_bitposts.tpl"}
    {/section}
```

works fine on it's own.

Why is this happening and what is the way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, was an error in my smarty code later on